# How can i show the Redo Last panel in the Preferences?

Tags: python, scripting

The redo last panel is one time at the bottom of the tool shelf. And you can also call it with <kbd>F6</kbd>.

I would love to display this panel in the Properties though. Which, in my opinion, makes much more sense. The redo last panel seems to be a menu, at least the version that can be called with <kbd>F6</kbd>. So I tried it with a simple `layout.menu("SCREEN_OT_redo_last", text="none")`

But that way I get a warning that the menu `SCREEN_OT_redo_last` does not exist.

So what would be the way to add the redo last panel to the Properties editor? Am I even at the right track?

```
import bpy

class ObjectPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Redo Last panel"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "render"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.menu("SCREEN_OT_redo_last", text="none")

bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
```

[image: I would love to display the Repeat Last Panel as shown here]

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41985/making-the-buttonpress-f6-into-a-scripted-button  `SCREEN_OT == bpy.ops.screen.`

Comment: Thx. But this just calls the popup again. Like with pressing F6. I would like to show the content in the panel. Not sure what SCREEN_OT == bpy.ops.screen should tell me.

Comment: Solved by this script. It has some caveats though. The affected object does not update when i change a value here. Which is already another thread. See here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57700/custom-redo-last-object-does-not-update-when-changing-value

    import bpy
    ...
    for element in     bpy.context.window_manager.operators[-1].properties.keys():
                        column.prop(bpy.context.window_manager.operators[-1].properties, element)